# Text not flowing correctly around floated elements in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

Please see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VaBCd/

...view in Chrome (I've got v14) and then any other browser.

Notice how in Chrome the text  is failing to break at the right place with respect to the 2nd div, which has  `{float:right;clear:both}`.

What's the best (preferably non-hack) way to deal with this so as to provide a consistent layout across browsers with the greatest flexibility?

Comment: This looks like a rendering bug to me. Please file it on http://new.crbug.com and be sure to include the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @Boris: bug filed: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=98558